# Handling arrays with express post request

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using express to make the API for my web app. Below is the Schema for my annual budgets collection.

```js
var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose'); 


var budgets = new mongoose.Schema({
        year: Number, 
        categories: [{
            name: String,
            amount: Number
        }]
}); 

var Budgets = mongoose.model('Budgets', budgets); 

module.exports = {
    Budgets
};
```

I am trying to passing in an array of categories using postman in the following way:

```js
{
 "year":2018,
 "categories": [{
  "name":"Logistics",
  "amount":1500
 }, {
  "name":"Finance",
  "amount":23030
 }]
}
```

This the post request for my this collection. The request times out and is not saved in the database. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the request. Please help

```js
app.post('/annualBudgets', (req, res) => {
            var categories = req.body.categories; 
            var budgets = new Budgets({
                year : req.body.year,
            }); 
            budgets.categories.push(categories);

            budgets.save().then((docs) => {
                res.send(docs);
                console.log(docs)
            }).catch((e) => res.status(404)); 
        });
```

Comment: no exception thrown? what happens after `budgets.categories.push(categories);`?

Comment: It gives me a cast error. Message says cast to ObjectID failed for the values in the categories object.

Comment: are you passing id somehwere? categories coming from postman have id?

Comment: Nope, I'm just passing in the year and the categories array

Comment: cool, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
budgets.categories.push(categories);
```

it should be

```
budgets.categories = categories;
// Alternatively 
// budgets.categories.push(...categories);
```

because `categories` is already an `array`.